# determine if chipset is capable off packet injection and monitor mode

Tags: linux, live, wifi, chipset

and I want to know if my chipset is capable off doing those things

My chipset is a **intel centrino advanced 6200-n** on a sony vayo laptop running on windows 7.

Now, I know that windows is only capable off listening, so I boot backtrack 4
from a usb stick.

I also want to know if a live distribution can work  flawlessly with the wificard even if it does not support formentioned things, because I try'd to use wget to download something
and it says it ca not resolve the address?

thanks, Richard

Comment: You can find some suitable cards to use here: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers&DokuWiki=01c89160d88dc29d91c1546165ca8089#compatibility.
happy wardriving..

Comment: thanks, I have been there already, it go's sofar as 5xxx, but not the 6000 series yet. Somewhere else, I saw that it is possible to add the firmware somehow, but it was an incomplete posting. So, I am stuck again.I guss I can try to run kismet, to see if it gives some data back?

Comment: kismet is not working either?

Comment: Could you found any answer? did you try something? I have this card too, and wondering if I can use it with air-crack. can you please write what your conclusions? 10x

Comment: I haven't really followed up on it. There are some lists available if you search for it, but they have to be compatible with the kind off software that you use and hardware. I remember there was something about windows that made it impossible. Problably need to assemble some kind off linux laptop. Trackback forum can possibly help you also.

Comment: I am confused, so you have been wardriving, just not with aircrack? Why don't you trying installing everything and running/testing the commands with your card?

Answer (score 1):

Intel centrino advanced 6200-n **does support both monitor mode and frame injection** with iwlwifi driver. There are some intricacies involved on driver side though so it is best to use very recent kernel to make it work reliably. The patches which make this work well are expected to be part of Linux kernel version 3.5, until it's released you can build kernel yourself from iwlwifi.git tree:
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.git

Instructions on building kernel from a git tree:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

It *should* also work with older kernels.

As for the fact that you couldn't wget something - have you connected to wireless network at all? Standard client mode in iwlwifi works very well even with old kernels.